# Can a QFutureWatcher be used to monitor multiple serial tasks all run with QConcurrent?

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuture

I have a series of tasks that need to happen on a set of images. There are 3 steps which I want to run one after each other, but the middle one needs to be run serially because it relies on the results of all the previous iterations. What I want is to relay the progress of these three tasks back to the UI using a `QFutureWatcher`. I already have other tasks that do this and hook into progress bars etc, so kinda what to use the same process if I can. The way I'm thinking of implementing is to have an internal `QFuture` and `QFutureWatcher` that runs each task, and one external `QFutureWatcher` that monitors this an relays info to the UI. Maybe something like this (pseudo code):

```
runProcessingTask() {
    connect(externalFutureWatcher, UI elements)
    internalFuture = start first task 
    internalFutureWatcher.setFuture(internalFuture)
    connect(internalFuture.finished(), taskfinished())
    connect(internalFuture.progressValue(), updateProgress())
    taskNumber = 1
}

taskFinished() {
    switch(taskNumber):
    case 1:
        internalFuture = start second task 
        internalFutureWatcher.setFuture(internalFuture)
        taskNumber = 2
    case 2:
        internalFuture = start third task 
        internalFutureWatcher.setFuture(internalFuture)
        taskNumber = 3
    case 3:
        externalFutureWatcher.setFinished()
}

updateProgress() {
    switch(taskNumber):
    case 1:
        extrenalFutureWatcher.setProgress(internalFutureWatcher.progress() / 3)
    case 2:
        extrenalFutureWatcher.setProgress(33.3% + (internalFutureWatcher.progress() / 3))
    case 3:
        extrenalFutureWatcher.setProgress(66.6% + (internalFutureWatcher.progress() / 3))
}
```

Would this sort of thing be possible? Do I just need to override some methods in `QFutureWatcher` and use them as my externalFutureWatcher? Or is it not possible in this way/ is there a much better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you better simplify the conditions, try use `QFutureSynchronizer`

Comment: Are you running the tasks concurrently (i.e. using `QtConcurrent::run`)?

Comment: Yes I'm running the tasks concurrently